# Service Fabric use Entity Framework with Authentication=Active Directory Password

Tags: entity-framework, azure-active-directory, azure-service-fabric

We have a project used Service Fabric and EF(6.1.3 and 6.2.0-beta1), but the connect string used Azure AD password. I tested connect string works in local in a console application(I installed SSMS 17.2). But it don't work in cluster.

Always have error:

> Unable to load adalsql.dll (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword).
>   Error code: 0x2.

I researched for a long time, but can't find usefully solution.

The connect string is like the following:

```
Server=tcp:server,1433;Initial Catalog=dbname;
Persist Security Info=False;
UserID=user;
Password=password;
MultipleActiveResultSets=False;
Encrypt=True;
TrustServerCertificate=False;
Authentication=Active Directory Password;
```

Can someone tell me how to include `adalsql.dll` in cluster? Does it have Nuget package?

Comment: Do you try download the dll from the [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48742)?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT Yes I tried it and copy dll to include in project, but still not work

Comment: Did you choose the x64 install?

Comment: @LoekD Yes, I choosed x64 install

Comment: @LoekD I think I had to install adalsql.msi in Azure cluster, but how do I do it in local cluster

Comment: To install an msi on all nodes of the cluster, you can use an ARM template that executes a PowerShell DSC script, with the Custom Script VM extension. https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/blog/automating-vm-configuration-using-powershell-dsc-extension/

Comment: @LoekD Thank you, I will try it